# How to play song URL on MPMusicplayerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

So I want to play song using it's url using `MPMusicPlayer`. I already able to populate music info from `MPMediaCollection` to `UITableView`. What I want to do is when I tap `tableview` row it play song that have the same title in the `tableview` row.

Here is my code how I populate music info

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!,

    didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!){



        for thisItem in mediaItemCollection!.items as! [MPMediaItem]{



            var mediaitem = mediaItemCollection!.items



            playlistItem = ["music" : mediaitem]

            playlistItemArray.addObject(playlistItem!)



            let itemUrl = thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL)

                as? NSURL



            let itemTitle =

            thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)

                as? String



            let itemArtist =

            thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)

                as? String



            var itemArtwork: AnyObject! = thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork)

            if (itemArtwork != nil) {

                var listArtwork = itemArtwork.imageWithSize(CGSizeMake (198, 198))

                var listArtworkData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(listArtwork)



                playlistArtwork = ["picture" : listArtworkData]

                playlistArtworkImage.addObject(playlistArtwork!)

            }else{

                var listNulArtwork = UIImage(named: "noArtworkImage.png")

                var listNulArtworkData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(listNulArtwork)

                playlistArtwork = ["picture" : listNulArtworkData]

                playlistArtworkImage.addObject(playlistArtwork!)

            }



            playlist = ["title" : itemTitle! , "artist" : itemArtist! , "songUrl" : itemUrl!]

            playlistArray.addObject(playlist!)



        }



}
```

and here is the code , how i populate data to tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playlistCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let object = User.playList[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let artworkObject =  User.playlistArt[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    let base64String = artworkObject["picture"]!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView).image = decodedimage
    //(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView).image = image.timelinecircleMask
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = object["title"] as? String
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel).text = object["artist"] as? String

    return cell
}
```

and here is my screenshot of my playlist tableview

[image]

**What I get from MPMediaCollection are dictionary of mpmediaitem and song info(title, artist, url)**

How can I play the song when I tap `uitableview` row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Yes I've solved this problem by myself. It's really simple actually

first thing I do is:

> declare **MPMediaItemcollection** as a global variable(put in a ***struct***)

then:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    var mediaItemCollection = User.mdci
    MPMusicPlayerController().nowPlayingItem = mediaItemCollection!.items[indexPath.row] as! MPMediaItem
    MPMusicPlayerController().play()

    getPlayingSongInfo()

}
```

just like that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) to play the song.

Declare a property like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

Initialise your player like this:

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url     
                                                          error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

To play the song use:

```
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already solved it by myself :). I just make mpmediacollection golobal, then I put play action to didSelectRowAtIndexPath